# Copy and Paste Remotely

Tags: scripts, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently setup an Ubuntu virtual machine on Azure. I can access that machine via SSH. I'm trying to copy a bash script I have in my browser window. I want to paste that into a file on my virtual machine. In an attempt to do that, I created a new file on my Ubuntu virtual machine using Nano. I then tried to copy-and-paste however the script that I've copied isn't getting pasted.

I'm accessing the virtual machine via SSH via the Bash shell on Windows 10. Is there a way to copy-and-paste? if so how? If not, can someone please recommend how I might be able to get the bash script I want into the virtual machine without manually typing the whole thing?

Thanks!

Comment: paste to console is with ctrl+shift+v did you try that?

Comment: I did. That did not work. However, there is a paste option in the bash shell app menu. I didn't see that there.

Comment: @ZachTempleton If you've solved copy and paste via clipboard can you post an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which virtual machine software you are using but in Oracles's Virtualbox you have to enable a share clipboard folder option. You can see how to do it [here](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/copy-paste-virtualbox-host-guest-machines/).

Another option is to use [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_install). If you are familiar with scp command in linux is exactly that with a gui interface. This way you can transfer files via ssh. Open winscp and connect just as you were ssh'ing. You can modify your files locally and then transfer them to your virtual machine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might transfer your data between machines with simple email hosting. But don't forget to archive and create safe password. Or encode it in any other safe way if it is critical data.